# If you know what it's mean? '%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A'

Tags: hex

I want to know what it's mean and What type.

Is it Hexadecimal?

Comment: Hexadecimal has a limited set of valid symbols; your string contains symbols not in that set so unless it's encoded, no, it's not hex.

Comment: If you want to know its "mean"ing or usage you'll have to provide some context. `%` could be a wildcard for `n` unknown characters in certain contexts so it's quit impossible to know by what you've provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the url encoding format. For normal characters the character is printer. That explains the PNG. For the non-printable characters , spaces, line feeds etc they use % followed by 2 hex digits.

%0D is carriage return
%0A is line feed

%89 is a percent sign with an extra 0 in the denominator.  0/00

%1A is the capital letter J.

It could be something else but seeing %0D%0A in sequence almost guarantees that it is hex.